# SharePoint 2016 On Premise Dev using SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-framework, typescript, nodejs, npm

This is my first question in this forum ;)

I need to develop SharePoint 2016 On Premises solution in Visual Studio using the SharePoint Framework.

i did some RnD over it and found a nice articles on microsoft website but the problem is that articles are only guiding me to develop local solutions and sharepont online solutions using the SPFx.

Click [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tools-and-libraries) to check out SPFx

for this, i did all steps mentioned in the tutorial and in the videos e.g installing Node.js, NPM, Visual studio code and creating tenant in sharepoint online.
also i have created a client side hello world webpart using type scripts etc.

it is working perfect but my question is how to develop SharePoint 2016 on premise solutions using the SharePoint Framework?

Thanks

Comment: Check the detail steps at [SPFx for SharePoint 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40217.spfx-for-sharepoint-server-2016.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SharePoint Feature Pack 2 from here:

[security update for SharePoint Server 2016: September 12, 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011127/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforsharepointserver2016september12-2017)

This update allows SPFX Development in SharePoint 2016 on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2** supports SharePoint Framework client-side web parts hosted in classic SharePoint pages.

More details including deployment options available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support).